# Sort JSON object in PHP by a key value

Tags: php, json, sorting

I need to sort this kind of information by the "score" value in a PHP script, how can I do? :

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Morts par DÃ©shydratation
        [score] => 4
        [id] => dwater
    )

 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => RÃ©parations de chantiers
        [score] => 87
        [id] => brep
    )

 [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Campeur tÃ©mÃ©raire
        [score] => 77
        [id] => camp
    )

 [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => DÃ©coration
        [score] => 112
        [id] => deco
    )
)
```

PS : This is already in a PHP value, I already used json_decode.*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Where `$data` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Morts par DÃƒÂ©shydratation
            [score] => 4
            [id] => dwater
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => RÃƒÂ©parations de chantiers
            [score] => 87
            [id] => brep
        )

    [.] => ....
)
```

You can use `usort()` to sort the array :

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                       
usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
    return $a->score > $b->score ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
});                                                                                                                                                                                                        

print_r($data);   
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => DÃ©coration
            [score] => 112
            [id] => deco
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => RÃ©parations de chantiers
            [score] => 87
            [id] => brep
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Campeur tÃ©mÃ©raire
            [score] => 77
            [id] => camp
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Drogues
            [score] => 49
            [id] => drug
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Ouverture de porte
            [score] => 11
            [id] => door
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Morts par DÃ©shydratation
            [score] => 4
            [id] => dwater
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. The data I use is already a PHP value, not a JSON. And when I apply your function to it, it only gives "1" as output.

Comment: Can you update your question with the PHP value rather than the JSON one so I can see what the data we're working with looks like?

Comment: Yeah here you go, sorry ^^

Comment: `usort($data, function($a, $b){ return strnatcmp($a->score, $b->score); });` would display it in national order..

Comment: If you need an ascedant order use "return $a-> score > $b-> score ? 1 : -1;"

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thanks!