# get json date by array in php

Tags: php, json

just sample data of json

```
{
    "title":"Wedding Hair Photo Montage",    
    "app_id":"com.blue.weddinghairphotomontage",    "developer":"Blue Photo Montage",
    "developer_id":"Blue Photo Montage",
    "image":"https://sampake.net/uda.jpg",
    "rating_width":"width: 66.66666507720947%;",
    "time":1469293200,"Version":"1.2"
}
```

my php code

```
<?php foreach( $recent_download as $key => $recent ) {
    get_template( 'templates/app-item', $recent );
}?>
```

i needed Sort data by time

Comment: use json_decode() ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something similar was asked before: [Sort JSON object in PHP by a key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779412/sort-json-object-in-php-by-a-key-value)

In case you are having trouble loading the JSON String into memory, you can use the following:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString,true);
```